# Can't setup reminder or calendar appointment using Siri on Mac

Tags: macos, siri

Any idea why I can't setup a reminder or calendar appointment with Siri on the Mac? When I attempt to setup a reminder I just get her saying "One sec". When I press confirm after telling her to setup an appointment I get "Sorry Scott I can't do that".
Any ideas? Is there something I have to do to get these useful features working?

Answer (score 2):

In System Settings, **grant permissions** to access Calendar and Location data for Siri, then disable and re-enable Siri.